# Object Oriented Programming

Tags: java

Object Oriented Programming..
I have a problem in my main method, it says cannot find symbol. why?

in this part:

```
double grossPay = payroll.getHoursWorked * payroll.getPayRate * payroll.getTaxRate ;
```

all I know is that I already declared it in my base class
in here:

```
public class Exercise1 {
    private long hoursWorked;
    private double payRate;
    private double taxRate;   


    public void setHoursWorked(long temp){
        hoursWorked = temp;
    }

    public void setPayRate (double temp){
        payRate = temp;
    }

    public void setTaxRate (double temp){
        taxRate = temp;
    }

    public double getTaxRate (){
        return(taxRate);
    }

    public double getPayRate (){
         return(payRate);
    }

    public double getHoursWorked (){
        return(hoursWorked);
    }
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public class payroll{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Exercise1 payroll = new Exercise1();
        payroll.setHoursWorked(28);
        payroll.setPayRate (120.00);
        payroll.setTaxRate (0.30);

        double grossPay = payroll.getHoursWorked * payroll.getPayRate * payroll.getTaxRate;
        System.out.println("Gross pay is:"+ grossPay);   
    }
}
```

why keeps asking "cannot find symbol" ?
please help.. I'm new to programming :(

Comment: you are missing method parantheses `()` for methods Try : `payroll.getHoursWorked() * payroll.getPayRate() * payroll.getTaxRate()`

Comment: you are kind of confusing java, as you have a variable named `payroll` within the class `payroll` you better use capitalized name for the class.

Comment: oh men.. look how stupid I am :-(
btw thank you very much :P
sorry about that.. cuz Im really new to programming.

Answer (score 4):

`getHoursWorked`, `getPayRate` etc are **methods**, and even though you pass them no parameters, they still need empty brackets in order to be invoked.

Replace them with `getHoursWorked()`, `getPayRate()` and you'll be laughing.

Comment: sorry about that sir cuz im really new to programming, im still a student.. and thank you.. it solved my problem

Comment: No probs my man.  Feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot () at the end of the function calls.

```
double grossPay = payroll.getHoursWorked() * payroll.getPayRate() * payroll.getTaxRate();
```

Comment: that solved my stupidity :P
thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
double grossPay = payroll.getHoursWorked() * payroll.getPayRate() * payroll.getTaxRate() ;
```

since `getHoursWorked` is method you need to call method as this `payroll.getHoursWorked()`

Answer (score 1):

Put () at the end of each func call.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
double grossPay = payroll.getHoursWorked() * payroll.getPayRate() * payroll.getTaxRate() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call method using (); Brackets call the method. like-

```
payroll.getHoursWorked() * payroll.getPayRate()
```